# What kind of Crocosmia are these?

Tags: identification, flowers

There are many of these Crocosmia growing in my garden in South East England and I would love to know the exact type. They have just started blooming in the last week or so.[image][image]

Comment: Can you add another photo taken from further away, showing the whole plant please? Need an idea of leaf to flower ratio, growth habit and its height and spread

Comment: Ok just added another photo. If it helps the max height of the foliage is about 70cm. It's popping up all over the place which is fine as I really like it. Just wish I knew more about it! Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is the one that grows wild here in the UK, commonly known as Montbretia, latin name Crocosmia crocosmifolia. Originally a French cross between two other crocosmia, it was introduced to the UK in 1880 as a garden plant, but escaped and spread widely from 1910 or so onwards. It is often seen in hedgerows in Cornwall particularly, but also Devon and Wales, and on wild land in the south east generally, as well as being ubiquitous in our gardens. You will not find it for sale anywhere, it's usually acquired by donation from someone else, or just appears. Newer hybrids and varieties generally have stiffer leaves, are often taller, usually flower a little earlier than yours, and the flower colours range from yellow through to bright red. Crocosmia 'Lucifer' is one of the best of the taller varieties.

The only image I can find is within a PDF document, and I have no clue how to link to this - it's a page on Montbretia from the GB Non Native Species Secretariat. Although there are other sites that come up if you Google montbretia, none of them show the now endemic variety which grows wild in Cornwall and the South East - they all show newer varieties.

Comment: Thank you so much for the information.  I found the page you are talking about and it seems to fit the description perfectly!

Answer (score 3):

It seems to be [Crocosmia Lady Hamilton](http://trecanna.com/super.asp?id=363&name=crocosmia+x+crocosmiiflora+%27lady+hamilton%27).

It's the best matches of descriptions found on [**Garden Guides**](http://www.gardenguides.com/116934-crocosmia-varieties.html):

> "Lady Hamilton" dons upright flower spikes filled with golden yellow blooms with centers blushed with apricot-yellow hues. It grows 24- to 30-inches tall.

[image]